# Groupby multiple columns with product aggregation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe with several items and counts as follows:

| index | item1 | item2 | item3 | count1 | count2 | count3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0.5 | 0.5 | 10 | 15 | 0 |
| 2 | 0.5 | 0 | 0.5 | 20 | 20 | 20 |
| 3 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 30 | 10 | 30 |
| 4 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 20 | 20 | 0 |

I want to `groupby` the data by items, aggregating with a product so that I end up with a Dataframe that has the items as index, the counts as columns and the values at cell i, j are equal to the sum of `item{i} * count{j}`. For instance:

| index | count1 | count2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| item1 | (0 * 10) + (0.5 * 20) + (1 * 30) + (0 * 20) = 40 | (0 * 15) + (0.5 * 20) + (1 * 10) + (0 * 20) = 20 |
| item2 | (0.5 * 10) + (0 * 20) + (0 * 30) + (1 * 20) = 25 | (0.5 * 15) + (0 * 20) + (0 * 10) + (1 * 20) = 27.5 |

I have tried using `groupby`:

```
df[items + counts].groupby(items).agg('prod')
```

and

```
df.groupby(items)[counts].agg('prod')
```

but the problem is that `groupby` uses the values of the column rather than the column themselves, and I'm running into the same issue with `pivot_table`:

```
df.pivot_table(index=items, values=counts, aggfunc='prod')
```

I feel like the solution should be trivial, but I can't quite put the finger on what I'm missing.

Comment: Where is item3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you could use [dot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) of *items* vs *counts*:

```
# create DataFrame with only item columns
items = df.filter(regex='^item')

# create DataFrame with only count columns
counts = df.filter(regex='^count')

# compute dot product
res = items.T.dot(counts)

print(res)
```

**Output**

```
       count1  count2  count3
item1    40.0    20.0    40.0
item2    25.0    27.5     0.0
item3    15.0    17.5    10.0
```

The *items* and *counts* DataFrames are obtained using [filter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html).